# What is difference between Join and doing same thing with subquery?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have tblProducts and NioaProducts.
tblProducts is look like this : 
id | productId | skuCode | manCode |.....

NioaProducts looks like this :
partNo | manuCode | price |....

Now, I am executing this two queries where I am getting different counts,

```
 SELECT     COUNT(manCode) AS Expr1
 FROM         tblProducts p
 WHERE     (manCode IN
                          (SELECT     manuCode
                            FROM          NioaProducts))
```

This gives me o / p: 10057

Now I am doing same thing with inner join

```
   SELECT     COUNT(manCode) AS Expr1
     FROM         tblProducts p inner join NioaProducts n on p.manCode = n. manuCode
```

This gives me o/p: 11481

I just want to know which query is correct and why both results are different?

Comment: does tblProducts and NioaProducts have one to one relation or one to many relation ?

Comment: That must be one-to-one relationship

Comment: Can you check using this query ? "Select manCode, count(*) as c from NioaProducts group by manCode having c > 1" - Just to confirm if the one to one relationship is maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Why the results are different ?
```

One possibility is one to many relationship.
Consider the following two tables

tblProducts -

```
manCode   Product
1         p1
2         p2
3         p3
```

NioaProducts -

```
manCode   NioaProductName
1         np1
2         np2
2         np3
```

When you run

```
SELECT     COUNT(manCode) AS Expr1
FROM         tblProducts p
WHERE     (manCode IN
                      (SELECT     manuCode
                        FROM          NioaProducts))
```

The subquery returns (1,2,2) therefore the query filters only 1 and 2 as result. so it returns 2.

But when you run the join query

```
SELECT     COUNT(manCode) AS Expr1
FROM         tblProducts p inner join NioaProducts n on p.manCode = n. manuCode
```

the result of the inner join is

```
tblProducts.manCode NioaProducts.manCode
1                   1
2                   2
3                   2
```

Therefore the count returns 3

Comment: Yes you are correct. Today morning, firstly I ran this query and got many counts for same manCode. So, it's not one-to-one relationship.